# The Ancient One awakens fast!

Tags: arkham-horror

At the end of each player's turn, you draw a Mythos card. The Mythos card (among other things) opens a gate to an Other World. This increases the Doom counter on the Ancient One.

For two players, each round the doom counter will go up by two (assuming the players don't close any gates). If the doom counter goes up to ten, this means the Ancient One awakens. So if the players are slow to close and seal gates, the Ancient One will awaken in 5 rounds. Is this correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Unlike the other phases, only the first player acts in the Mythos Phase** (check the first sentence about the Mythos phase in the rulebook page 9)

In your example you'd have 10 turns each before the GOO (Great Old One) awakens.  Some caveats:

- 10 is just a sample number, various GOO's have between 7 and 14 tokens allowed.
- Not all Mythos cards open a gate (Rumors for example).
- There may already be a gate there (no Doom token is placed).
- Gates can open via other circumstances (these also generate a Doom token).

**You can never be quite sure how many turns you have left.**   That's one of the great things about Arkham Horror.

The terror track is completely different.  The main way that it advances is due to having too many monsters in the outskirts.  It is pretty rare to fill the terror track, but you will see a building or two close fairly often.

For two players, you are allowed 6 monsters in the outskirts; if there are any more, then dump them and increment the terror track.  (Note that 8 less the number of players is always the maximum number of monsters allowed in the outskirts.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible that the ancient one will arrive by turn 5, since only the First Player performs this step. Additionally, not all Mythos cards will cause the doom track to advance. An explanation of different results from revealing a Mythos card are on [arkhamhorrorwiki.com.](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Mythos_phase) If the location already has an open gate, a monster surge occurs, and the doom track isn't advanced.

> The first player begins by looking at the lower-left corner of the mythos card he has drawn to see where the dimensional forces are assaulting Arkham this turn. One of three things happens, depending on whether there is an open gate, an elder sign marker, or neither at that location.
>
> **If Location Has No Elder Sign or Gate** - If there is neither an open gate nor an elder sign marker at the location, a new gate opens and a monster emerges from it. This means that the following things happen, in order:
>
> **The Doom Track Advances** - The first player places a doom token with the eye symbol face up in the first available space on the Ancient One’s doom track. ...
>
> **If Location Has an Open Gate** - If there is already an open gate at the location, a monster emerges from every open gate currently on the board. This is called a monster surge. A monster surge does not add a doom token to the Ancient One's doom track.